# Tips for iOS5 Development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, json, ios5

iOS 5's storyboard is awesome but I've read that it would be better to not use it unless the app market audience is only iOS 5 users.

Have you other tips for the iOS 5 features? My app is targeted to iOS4/iOS5 market audience, should I continue to use only XIB files for the view design? And should I continue to use the third party JSON Framework instead the new built in JSON?

Comment: I didn't answer your XIB question because I wasn't quite sure what you were asking. Are you asking if you should maintain both XIB based views for 4.x devices and Storyboards for 5.x?

Comment: Not a real answer but I highly recommend you to visit this site - http://www.raywenderlich.com. They have a very good tutorial series on iOS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any particular tips for iOS 5 features, as it really is up to you which to implement into your application, and as far as supporting iOS4/5 is concerned, that too is a decision you must make. You should look at what features in 5.0 that you would like to support, and how to handle the absence of these new features in older versions.

How to do this? You weak link to libraries and frameworks that are only in 5.0, and you check if [methods are available prior to calling them](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html).

Lastly, if you're already comfortable with a third party JSON library, I would continue to use it, as you likely will not see much of an improvement in performance over Apple's new parser.